# After importing urllib2_file library my code is not working for proxy handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

without importing urllib2_file my code works fine .

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import random
import mimetypes
import string
import urllib2_file

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '10.200.1.26'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
u = urllib2.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:3333/command/core/create-importing-job",data=urllib.urlencode({"test":""}))
print u.read()
```

After importing urllib2_file library its complaining :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/hari/latest refine code/trialrefine.py", line 11, in <module>
    u = urllib2.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:3333/command/core/create-importing-job",data=urllib.urlencode({"test":""}))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\urllib2_file.py", line 207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTP, req)
  File "C:\Python27\urllib2_file.py", line 298, in do_open
    return self.parent.error('http', req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a [404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). it means the url was wrong/server was down. note that `urllib2_file` overwrites the default HTTP handler of urllib2 :

```
urllib2._old_HTTPHandler = urllib2.HTTPHandler
urllib2.HTTPHandler = newHTTPHandler
```

one thing you could do is explicitly pass the `urllib2._old_HTTPHandler` to the opener. Other than that you really should go into the `urllib2_file` with a debugger to understand whats going wrong.